# Execute bash script in a new Terminal and pass variable as argument

Tags: bash

I am working on an Apple server and I have two bash scripts (A & B).  The entry point is script A and it accepts two arguments  (1 & 2).  During the execution of script A, script B needs to be called and executed in a new terminal.  Script B also needs to be passed the value of argument 2.

Comment: Why does it need to be in a "new terminal"?

Comment: it needs to execute asynchronously from the rest of the script

Comment: You don't need a new terminal for that.

Comment: What would you suggest then?

Comment: call script "B" with an `&` (send to background)

Comment: If you need to, you can wait for B to finish by calling `wait` in A.

Comment: Expanding on Donovan's comment, in "A" you'd call `B "$2" &`

Comment: Thanks everyone, that did accomplish what I wanted.  My lack of bash experience is showing :). I didn't even know enough to know what to Google, so you guys saved me.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Donovan's comment, in "A" you'd call `B "$2" &` – glenn jackman